# Render UIWebView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiwebview

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

I have a tableCell and inside it I have a stackView and inside it a UIWebview added programatically.

```
class ChatTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet var stackView: UIStackView!
  func setupCell(message: ChatMessage) {

        addHtmlToView(msg: "<p>This is <b>bold text</b></p>")
    }

 func addHtmlToView(msg: String) {
         let webView = UIWebView()
        webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body><div id='mainHtml'>" + msg + "</div></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        webView.isOpaque = false
        webView.delegate = self
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        webView.scrollView.bounces = false
        webView.backgroundColor = .red
        webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -8, left: -8, bottom: -8, right: -8)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(webView)

        heightWebViewConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        widthWebViewConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 1)

         webView.addConstraint(heightWebViewConstraint)
         webView.addConstraint(widthWebViewConstraint)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([ heightWebViewConstraint, widthWebViewConstraint])

    }
}

extension ChatTableViewCell: UIWebViewDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebView.NavigationType) -> Bool {
       if navigationType == UIWebView.NavigationType.linkClicked {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(request.url!)
        return false
    }
    return true
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    webView.frame.size.height = 1.0        
    webView.sizeToFit()

    let result = NumberFormatter().number(from: webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('mainHtml').offsetHeight") ?? "0")

    heightWebViewConstraint.constant = 200        
}
```

}

After this the cell render like this [image]
Next I will use the value from "result" but this doesn't work with an hardcoded value either

[image]

Comment: One thing you have not done is to add your width and height constraints to anything (as far as the code shows).  You create them and assign them to variables and then attempt to activate them but where do you actually add them to any view.  You probably need to add them to the web view and maybe also add some other constraints to pin down its position.

Comment: I did when I wrote this -> heightWebViewConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView ....) and this webView is inside a StackView design on Xib

Comment: No all that does is to create the constraint it doesn't add it to any view.  You need to do something like `webView.addConstraint(heightWebViewConstraint`.

Comment: i wil edit my code but that doesnt work and the cell look like the same XD

Comment: Well that was just my initial thought on one problem there could be others.  First I would suggest updating the code with how you are adding the constraint now.  Also how is the stack view setup and how are the constraints for the other parts of the cell setup.  Also what are you expecting because it's only going to be 1 point wide and 10 high.

Comment: I added a picture of my Xib, I updated my code with two lines where I am adding the constraints. the height should be 200 because I am changing to that value on "webViewDidFinishLoad" no?

Comment: Sorry my bad on the height I forgot to scroll all the way down.  Of course depending on how the stack view is constrained you might not get a height of 200 and some constraints could break.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182020/discussion-between-francisco-castro-and-upholder-of-truth).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to Add Distribution property of Stack view as "Fill Equally"

[image]